# Power Bi Eliminate Hard Coding in Measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have many measures created with different sets of values Hard-Coded.

For example, user name, Month, etc., and these values change once in 3 months or so.

Meas1 = CALCULATE(sum(Project[Amount]), DATEVALUE(Project[Period])=DATEVALUE("2021-09-15"))

Above 2021-09-15 is in multiple places, I would like to eliminate this hard coding within the measure. And if the month value changes to 2021-12-15 for example, would like to make it in a single place and all the measure gets updated accordingly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

I tried the below suggestion to use Testdate = datevalue("2021-09-15").
this is not giving the expected result for me.

In this case, I cannot use Testdate directly I get this error. 'A function 'calculate' has been used in true/false expression....', so I used filter.

Meas1 = CALCULATE(sum(Project[Amount]), filter(Project, DATEVALUE(Project[Period])= Project[Testdate]))

But now the expected result changes. Please see thebelow img.

[image]

Hard Coding gives me the expected results.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 1):

You can create a measure:

TestDate = DATEVALUE("2021-09-15")

you can then reference this measure in all the others. Once you need to change it, you change it only in the TestDate measure.

You can also create it as a Parameter in the report. That way, you would be able to change it in the Power BI service directly when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SamBouKoa.

Comment: Please check my update on the original question.

Comment: you need to add all selected to your measure: CALCULATE(sum(Project[Amount]), filter(ALLSELECTED(Project), DATEVALUE(Project[Period])= Project[Testdate]))

Comment: Thanks, Mate, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please mark the answer as correct?